# Apollo prelaunch timeline?

Tags: apollo-program, reference-request, launch-sequence

I'm looking for a resource that will tell me all the important pre-launch events of an Apollo mission from when the rocket rolls out of the VAB to liftoff. Specifically, I'm interested in the Apollo 8 mission. Does anyone know of a book or website or video I can look at with this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a general, early overview of the operations in [Saturn V Apollo Launch Operations Plan](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19630012156/downloads/19630012156.pdf). It starts on document page 15.

[Stages to Saturn](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19970009949/downloads/19970009949.pdf) Appendix B has some general summary info as well.

There are detailed post-mission reports for Apollo 8 that go over the countdown to some extent

- [Saturn 5 Launch Vehicle, Flight Evaluation Report AS-503, Apollo 8 Mission](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19690015314/downloads/19690015314.pdf)
- [Apollo 8 Mission Report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19700033031/downloads/19700033031.pdf)

[image]

(from the mission report)

I've been looking for a detailed Saturn V countdown myself. So far I've only found a Saturn-1B [countdown](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19750016724/downloads/19750016724.pdf) and a Saturn V scrub-turnaround countdown - it's [Volume 2](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19720020267/downloads/19720020267.pdf) of the countdown documents and I'd sure like to find Volume 1...

Comment: My friend, you've done it! That's as much or more information than I needed. Can't thank you enough. All the best!

Comment: @EricSchlelein thank you, and welcome to space stack exchange.

Comment: There is 01:00:00 Start RP-1 level adjust and 0:35:00 RP-1 level adjust complete, but I miss Start RP-1 loading

Comment: @Uwe I'm away from a real pc now. Suspect the first stage fuel loading happened before that chart starts.

Comment: @Uwe The SA-507 Fight Manual shows RP-1 loading on 10/20/69. The countdown started a couple of weeks later, on 11/8/69. https://i.imgur.com/jdq5Hcf.png

Comment: Thanks for looking. RP-1 may be stored in the rockets tank for some weeks without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

book 'Stages to Saturn' by Bilstein;  history of development and building of Saturn I, I-B, and Saturn V.  Appendix b, 'list of selected events--starts at T minus 9hrs and goes through TLI.  Similar to above w/ more detail, 2 full pages.

Comment: A pdf of this book can be found at the 2nd link in my answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).